# what is the best approach to testing permissions in a REST application using pytest?

Tags: python-3.x, rest, api, automation, pytest

I am trying to automate a REST-based application using pytest and Python 3.7.

The application supports 3 different user roles (`manager`, `admin`, `consumer`) and each user has restriction in accessing the data.

Each user role will have different user name and API key.

For example, imagine the application has `data1`, `data2`, `data3`, `data4`, and `data5`.

- call API with `manager` role user and its API key, you will get access to all data from `data1` to `data5`.
- call API with `admin` role user and its API key, you will get access to only `data3` and `data4`.
- call API with `consumer` role user and its API key, you will get access to only `data2`.

The application is complicated but I am trying to simplify the application features.

What is the best approach to validate REST API with all these 3 different user roles or any suggestion to use some library.

Comment: Are you using a framework like Flask or Django?

Comment: @ZachValenta application is based on flask framework

Answer (score 0):

How about breaking down your tests by role:

```
assert has_access(consumer, data2) is True
assert has_access(consumer, [data1, data3, data4, data5]) is False
```

As the application becomes more complex, a next step might be to switch from role-based permissions to action-based i.e. instead of giving consumers full access to `data2`, you can create a `read` permission and give consumers only that permission for `data2`.